# SQL Server Report Builder - Sum Value with Unique Dates in a Month

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I'm working in MS SQL Server Report Builder and I'm looking to create a resource allocation report that is group by Year, Month and Days. The grouping for days make sense but I can't get the Month and Year to work the way I want..

E.g. Mary's worked on Task3 and Task4 which are on the same day. Her capacity is 8 for 2015-1-5. When grouped by Month (January) the calcuation sums a total of 22 (6+8+8). I would like the calculation for her capacity on 2015-1-1 to be 8 as the Capacity that day is only eight and not the capacity sumation of the two task.

I'm just not understanding the Report Builder enough to figure this out and I'm out of ideas... Any recommendations will help! Thanks!

```
ProjectName TaskName    ResourceName    ResourceManager AssignmentWork  TimeBYDay   Capacity    
Project1    Task1       Mary            ManagerA        8               2015-1-1    6
Project1    Task2       Jake            ManagerB        7.5             2015-1-2    4
Project2    Task3       Mary            ManagerA        4               2015-1-5    8
Project3    Task4       Mary            ManagerA        1               2015-1-5    8
Project3    Task5       Jake            ManagerB        2               2015-1-5    7
Project4    Task6       Robert          ManagerB        2               2015-1-5    7.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the MAX function within the report builder or the query and group by ProjectName, Task, ResoruceName, and etc.